# Ошибка в 1С 8.3: Неопознанный оператор

Tags: 1с

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ОбработкаКоманды(ПараметрКоманды, ПараметрыВыполненияКоманды)
    
    ТабДок = Новый ТабличныйДокумент;
    Печать(ТабДок; ПараметрКоманды);
    ТабДок.Показать("Транспортная накладная");  
    
КонецПроцедуры
```

При попытке запустить пользовательский режим выдаёт ошибку:

```
{АИС Документ.ТН.Команда.Печать.МодульКоманды(6,15)}: Ожидается символ ')'
    Печать(ТабДок<<?>>; ПараметрКоманды); (Проверка: Сервер)
{АИС Документ.ТН.Команда.Печать.МодульКоманды(6,32)}: Неопознанный оператор
    Печать(ТабДок; ПараметрКоманды<<?>>); (Проверка: Сервер)
{АИС Документ.ТН.Команда.Печать.МодульКоманды(6,15)}: Ожидается символ ')'
    Печать(ТабДок<<?>>; ПараметрКоманды); (Проверка: Тонкий клиент)
{АИС Документ.ТН.Команда.Печать.МодульКоманды(6,32)}: Неопознанный оператор
    Печать(ТабДок; ПараметрКоманды<<?>>); (Проверка: Тонкий клиент)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему эта ошибка возникла и как её можно исправить.

Answer (score 1):

> Печать(ТабДок; ПараметрКоманды);

После "ТабДок" вместо точки с запятой должна быть просто запятая.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь) Понятие не имею, как так получилось.

Comment: Всякое бывает :)